# How do I make 2 random choice variables in one line? (discord.py)

Tags: python, variables, discord, discord.py

Just keeps on saying

```
  await ctx.send("{}:".format(random.choice(a_var1)), "{}:".format(random.choice(a_var1)))
    TypeError: send() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
    async def a_message(ctx):
        a_var1 = [
            "a1",
            "a2",]
        a_var2 = [
            "b1",
            "b2",]
        await ctx.send("{}:".format(random.choice(a_var1)), "{}:".format(random.choice(a_var2)))
```

Like, how do you make it say "a1:b2", Instead of only "a1". If anybody could help me, that would much appreicated!

Comment: try `ctx.send("{}:".format(random.choice(a_var1)) + "{}:".format(random.choice(a_var2)))`

Comment: my question might've sound dumb and simple, but thank you!

Comment: No problem! Please accept my answer, if it answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should concatenate the strings. You are passing them as arguments.

You can use

```
ctx.send("{}:".format(random.choice(a_var1)) + "{}:".format(random.choice(a_var2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just replace the "," with "+" Like This to concatenate**

```
ctx.send("{}:".format(random.choice(a_var1)) + "{}:".format(random.choice(a_var2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to do

```py
await ctx.send("{0}:{1}:".format(random.choice(a_var1), random.choice(a_var2)))
```

I recommend you read the [discord.py Documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.send) and optionally read about [f-strings](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/f-string-formatting-in-python)